# Building quiz in Javascript: Select only one of dynamic elements plus the ability to change choice

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I try to build a quiz of 30 questions with dynamically generated elements.

The html:

```
  <div class="secondBox">
           <div class="questionBox">
           </div>
            
  </div>
```

Here's my script:

```
function showQuestion(){
    for(let i = 0; i < QuesPartA.length; i++){
      $(".questionBox").append('<div class="Question">Number '+ parseInt(i+1) +'</div>');
      QuesPartA[i]['option'].forEach(option => {
          $(".questionBox").append('<span class="pilihan">'+option +' </span><br>');  
      });
     
  } 

$(".secondBox").append('<a href="Listening Part A.html" class="btnToPartB">Continue to Part B</a>');
  };

$(".questionBox").on("click", ".pilihan", function() {
  $(this).css("background", "red");
  $('.pilihan').not(this).css("background", "#ccc");
```

So the dynamically generated element will show 30 questions with four answer options each. I want to change the color of the option to be red once the user clicks, plus with the ability to change choice.

I can do that with the code above: I can choose an answer for question number 1 (one of the options change to red), but when I click an answer for number 2, the chosen option in question 1 goes back to `#ccc` color. It goes the same way when I choose an option in question 3, the chosen answers for number 2 and 1 go back to `#ccc`.

Does anyone have any ideas so that everytime I click an answer for the next question the previous ones remain red?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the `.not()` always fails in this line:

```
$('.pilihan').not(this).css("background", "#ccc");
```

Which results in the background being changed to `#ccc`.

Try just removing that whole line...

```
$('.pilihan').not(this).css("background", "#ccc");
```

This should also cause any line that was turned red to remain red.

Comment: The reason I put that line is to give the ability to users to change their choices. Without  ```$('.pilihan').not(this).css("background", "#ccc");``` the users cannot change their choices but end up add one more choice. In other words, there will be more redded choices in one question. 

What I want to do is give the ability to change choices but limiting only one choice (one red) in one question.

Comment: @Ciptaning - try this `$('.pilihan').not(this).siblings().css("background", "#ccc");`

Comment: @Ciptaning - Seeing your html would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your help, ``` $('.pilihan').not(this).siblings().css("background", "#ccc");``` doesn't work as my intention. It changes the background of text 'Number 1, 2 etc' (not the choices) to be ```#ccc```. I just added my html. Thanks again for your help, sir.